# Run a random, procedurally generated load test for my web application

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, jmeter, load-testing

**What I'm trying to do:**

Send http requests to my web application from a dynamic workflow. I would like the load tester (Jmeter) to generate it's own workflow and post/get content to/from my site.

**What I have done:**

I have a dummy Wordpress site that I'm using to test the CPU and memory utilization on my host machines as well as the efficiency of my load balancing algorithm. Currently, I'm using Jmeter to design my workflow and test my system. However, I realized that Jmeter is only sending the same workflow to the load balancer. Due to this, the resource utilization on my backend servers are equal across the board. I would like to test and utilize the differences in CPU utilization. Therefore, I need a way to dynamically post/receive content from my dummy Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now JMeter is not able to automatically generate end-to-end test plan simulating real users doing various stuff to your application, the options are in:

1. Recording anticipated Wordpress user activities using JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and after [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters and [parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) of test data (i.e. usernames) you should be able to conduct a more or less realistic load test
2. Using a ready scripts collection like [WordPress JMeter Template](https://github.com/jmeter-templates/wordpress)
3. Use a machine-learning AI-based test tool like [up9](https://up9.com/)
4. If you're testing a web site behind the load balancer make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your test plan.

Comment: For your fourth point, I'm not sure if it is necessary in my case. I'm not familiar with the concept, but the users should only be seeing the IP of my load balancer. The DNS cache manager is for systems in which all backend IPs are visible no?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the requests under [Random Order Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Order_Controller)

> Random Order Controller is much like a Simple Controller in that it will execute each child element at most once, but the **order of execution of the nodes will be random**